# How to get the resourceId when granting an appRoleAssignment to a ServicePrincipal in Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to Grant Admin Consent of a API in an Azure AD application through Graph API. I created the App, created its Client Secret, then created a Service Principal to which I want to add AppRoleAssignment.
The API call to do so requires three attributes in the body ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http))

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment
{
    PrincipalId = {Input the Service Principal Id},
    ResourceId = {? Where to get this value?},
    AppRoleId = {Input the App role of the API I added to my Azure AD App}
};

await graphClient.ServicePrincipals["{servicePrincipal-id}"].AppRoleAssignments
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(appRoleAssignment);
```

My question is where to get the ResourceId from? Knowing that this is different from one tenant to the other.
Please note that if I grant the admin consent manually, then run this API call

```
var appRoleAssignments = GraphAppClient.ServicePrincipals[servicePrincipalId].AppRoleAssignments.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

Then revoke the consent, get the ResourceId from what the API returned, and then use it in the original call, the admin consent works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the `appRoleAssignment` resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approleassignment?view=graph-rest-1.0) says the following about the `resourceId` property:

> The unique identifier (`id`) for the resource service principal for which the assignment is made.

A good approach to find a service principal in a tenant is to search the `servicePrincipals` collection, filtering on the `appId` or `servicePrincipalName` properties.For example, to search for the Microsoft Graph service principal by its identifier URI:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals
    ?$filter=servicePrincipalNames/any(n:n eq 'https://graph.microsoft.com')
```

Or to find it by its `appId`:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals
    ?$filter=appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'
```

With the Microsoft Graph SDK for .NET, this would look something like this:

```cs
var r = await graphServiceClient.ServicePrincipals
    .Request()
    .Filter("appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'")
    .GetAsync();
```

Using Microsoft Graph PowerShell, things look very similar:

```
$r = Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'"
```

Using the Azure portal, each app under "Enterprise apps" corresponds to a service principal, and the "Properties" page shows its object ID.

(Once you have the service principal, you can use its `appRoles` collection to see the list of app roles it publishes, often useful to get the app role's `id`, which you'll need for  the `appRoleId` property.)

Comment: Hi Philippe. Thank you. Yes, I figured that out and posted it in my answer. Your answer though is a lot better documented. I appreciate it. I will accept it as an answer. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up figuring it out. The resourceId of every set of permission you are trying to add is the objectId of the app in Entreprise Applications. It sounds very confusing, but if you are trying to add Graph API permissions, you need to go to enterprise applications, find GraphAPI, and then find its ObjectId. That is your resourceId.
[image]